# Around similar inequalities than an inequality due to Nicolas, that involve products of consecutive Ramanujan primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, arithmetic-functions

This is cross-posted (and this post is a version to ask just around the veracity of Conjecture 1) as the post with identifier **3594907** and same [*title*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3594907/around-similar-inequalities-than-an-inequality-due-to-nicolas-that-involve-prod)), that I've edited on Mathematics Stack Exchange two years and six months ago.

I wondered if it is possible to prove or refute some of the following conjectures involving finite products of Ramanujan primes that are denoted in this post as $R_j$, I add as reference the Wikipedia [*Ramanujan prime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_prime). To create these inequalities I was inspired in Nicolas criterion for the Riemann hypothesis (see [1]).

**Definition.** *For each integer* $k\geq 1$ *we denote as* $$\mathcal{R}_k=\prod_{j=1}^k R_j$$ *the product of the first* $k$ *Ramanujan primes* $R_j$.

For example $\mathcal{R}_3=2\cdot 11\cdot 17=374$.

In this post we denote the Euler's totient function with $\varphi(n)$.

From previous definitions I was inspired in Nicolas criterion, and in the computational evidence of a Pari/GP script I've stated the following conjectures.

**Conjecture 1.** *For all integer* $k>116$ *we've that the inequality* $$\frac{\mathcal{R}_k}{\varphi(\mathcal{R}_k)}<\frac{1}{2}\log\log \mathcal{R}_k\tag{1}$$
*holds.*

**Conjecture 2.** *For all integer* $k\geq 1$ *we've that the inequality* $$\frac{1}{3}\log\log \mathcal{R}_k <\frac{\mathcal{R}_k}{\varphi(\mathcal{R}_k)}\tag{2}$$
*holds.*

> **Question.** How to prove the first conjecture? If this conjecture is difficult to elucidate I'm asking about what work can be done about it. **Many thanks.**

We need to estimate $\mathcal{R}_k$ and $\prod_{1\leq j\leq k}\left(1-\frac{1}{R_j}\right)^{-1}$ (it is well-known that Euler's totient function is multiplicative). The first conjecture doesn't seem a sharp inequality, I believe that maybe there are counterexamples for the second conjecture since seems to me very sharp for the first few thousands of integers $k$'s.

### References:

[1] Jean-Louis Nicolas, *Petites valeurs de la fonction d’Euler*, J. Number Theory 17 (1983), no. 3, pp. 375–388.

Comment: I hope that the question (the veracity of Conjecture 1) is potentially interesting and you can to discuss it here. Many thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for the person who upvoted the post.

Comment: Ramanujan primes are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A104272. "Ramanujan primes are the least integers $R_n$ for which there are at least $n$ primes between $x$ and $x/2$ for all $x \ge R_n$."

Comment: Many thanks professor @GerryMyerson